# Invalid value of TX counter when delete vertexes with orientdb 2.1.x

Tags: java, orientdb

While deleting vertexes from a class with more than 1600000 instances using the console:

```
delete vertex program batch 5000
```

I encounter this error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Invalid value of TX counter
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.rollback(OTransactionOptimistic.java:175)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2595)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.close(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1137)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.post.OServerCommandPostCommand.execute(OServerCommandPostCommand.java:107)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.service(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:180)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:627)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
```

I don't run inside a transaction and I was able to reproduce the error with plocal and remote connection, with enterprise version v2.1.4.
The database was created with another server instance, but with the same major version (2.1.x).

**Update**

My database is really huge (~29G) but I managed to reproduce the issue with a smaller graph and starting the console with a small heap (-Xmx32M).

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = ...

OrientBaseGraph graph = factory.getTx();

graph.createVertexType("Program");
graph.createVertexType("Variable");

graph.getRawGraph().getLocalCache().setEnable(false);
graph.declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert());

try {                       
    Vertex vr = graph.addVertex("class:Program");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {               
        Vertex v;

        v = graph.addVertex("class:Variable");              
        graph.addEdge(null, v, vr, "has");              
    }
} finally {
   graph.shutdown();
}
```

**Update 2**

With orient enterprise 2.1.5, the error is a little bit different. I ran with remote connection (because I wasn't able to configure the logging in client console) and with the same memory restriction (-Xmx32M):

```
2015-11-02 11:50:49:936 FINE  {db=db1} Deleted record #13:468 v.2 [OLocalPaginatedStorage]{db=db1} Error on transaction commit
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OTransactionException: Transaction was committed more times than it is started.
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:160)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2653)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2622)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.commit(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:161)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.end(OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.java:279)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:437)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:90)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1538)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1519)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:72)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:33)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex$2.call(OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.java:212)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex$2.call(OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.java:207)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.runInTx(OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.java:130)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.java:207)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:90)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1538)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1519)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1319)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:396)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:223)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)

2015-11-02 11:50:54:101 FINE  {db=db1} Sent run-time exception to the client /127.0.0.1:37943: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Invalid value of TX counter [ONetworkProtocolBinary]
```

Comment: how can i reproduce this error?

Comment: @wolf4ood I updated the question with a sample.

Comment: @grossvater: I have a similar issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @Erik No, unfortunately, I wasn't.

Comment: I managed to move on but I'm not sure how I resolved the issue now. I remove all edges first and then all vertices. I also set MaxDirectMemorySize on the command line `XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=16288m`